# Calendar Control not showing text after changing nothing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

While implementing a Calendar into asp.net, I originally had text showing up on certain dates, pulling data from a DB. However, now, after changing nothing (to my knowledge), the text no longer appears, but the date box color does still change. Any help would be great. I am also new to asp.net, so it could be a simple mistake.

asp.net code:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar" runat="server" OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="300px" NextPrevFormat="FullMonth" Width="500px" >
        <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" />
        <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="4px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#333399" />
        <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    </asp:Calendar>
```

C# code behind:

```
public partial class HomePageStudent : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Lab3"].ConnectionString);
        String sqlQuery;
        Dictionary<string, string> importantDates = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            c.Open();
            DateTime day;

            sqlQuery = @"SELECT * From Internships";

            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, c);

                SqlDataReader rd;

                rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    day = (DateTime)rd["DateStart"];
                    if (day == e.Day.Date)
                    {
                        e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>" + "Application Due:\n" + rd["InternshipTitle"] + "<p>"));
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
                        e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Goldenrod;
                        e.Cell.Font.Bold = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
            c.Close();
        }
    }
```

I tried removing formatting and changing around the code a little bit, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I solve it a couple minutes after posting...

After renaming the dayrender method, that seemed to fix everything... somehow.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I'm glad you were able to solve your issue. Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), so you can better help someone having the same problem.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)